# Append multiple columns from a df into a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, append

I am trying to `import` `xy coordinates` from multiple `columns` into a list. I can get it going when the `coordinates` are read from a single `column` but struggling to get it to read from multiple `columns` efficiently.

I need this for plotting

Attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = ({
    'Time' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],       
    'GrA1_X' : [10,12,17,16,16,14,12,8],                 
    'GrA1_Y' : [10,12,13,7,6,7,8,8], 
    'GrA2_X' : [5,8,13,16,19,15,13,5],                 
    'GrA2_Y' : [6,15,12,7,8,9,10,8],
    'GrB1_X' : [15,18,25,16,6,15,17,10],                 
    'GrB1_Y' : [7,12,5,9,10,12,18,9], 
    'GrB2_X' : [10,4,18,14,16,12,17,4],                 
    'GrB2_Y' : [8,12,16,8,10,14,12,15],         
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

GrA_X = df[df.columns[1::2][:2]]
GrA_Y = df[df.columns[2::2][:2]]

GrB_X = df[df.columns[5::2][:2]]
GrB_Y = df[df.columns[6::2][:2]]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
ax = plt.gca()

Zs = []
for l,color in zip('AB', ('red', 'blue')):
    # plot all of the points from a single group
    ax.plot(GrA_X.iloc[0], GrA_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='red', ms=15, label=l, alpha = 0.5)
    ax.plot(GrB_X.iloc[0], GrB_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='blue', ms=15, label=l, alpha = 0.5)    

    Zrows = []
    for _,row in df.iterrows():
        x,y = row['Gr%s_X'%l], row['Gr%s_Y'%l]
```

I'm stuck with the `Zrows = []` call. Specifically, how to append `multiple` `columns` within this list.

Comment: Going through the code, I encountered a few fairly simple `pandas` errors. I'm wondering if it is necessary to post the entire code to resolve these issues. Anyway, the error that you list can be resolved by changing the line `dmin,dmax = min(d.min() for d in data), max(d.max() for d in data)` to `dmin,dmax = min(d.values.min() for d in data), max(d.values.max() for d in data)`. However this will lead to another error in your plotting command, because your data columns have now different names than in the first example.

Comment: @ThomasKühn. Thanks for this. I know there'll be more errors. I'll aim to work through them.Would it be easier to simplify it to the error, instead of the whole code?

Comment: I think if you would have written a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error you posted, you would have already gotten an answer, also without the bounty. To be honest, I don't think that anybody will go through the entire script and fix all the errors for you. The first (working) script produces a really nice plot btw.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasKuhn. I've gone through the first few errors. I think I'm down to the last error. I'll reduce it down.

Comment: Is this clearer @Thomas Kuhn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not clear whether I understand the purpose of the last loop correctly, but I'll take the risk and suggest a solution. Your problem seems to be with the naming of the columns and I don't see another way except looping over the different variations of `Gr{A,B}{1,2}_{X,Y}` (here the `{}` indicate variations). I would go with a nested `for`-loop, i.e.:

```
Zs = []
for l,color in zip('AB', ('red', 'blue')):
    # plot all of the points from a single group
    ax.plot(GrA_X.iloc[0], GrA_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='red', ms=15, label=l, alpha = 0.5)
    ax.plot(GrB_X.iloc[0], GrB_Y.iloc[0], '.', c='blue', ms=15, label=l, alpha = 0.5)    

    Zrows = []
    for _,row in df.iterrows():
        for i in [1,2]:
            x,y = row['Gr{}{}_X'.format(l,i)], row['Gr{}{}_Y'.format(l,i)]
            Zrows.append((x,y))


print(Zrows)
```

which gives a list of coordinate tuples:

```
[(15, 7), (10, 8), (18, 12), (4, 12), (25, 5), (18, 16), (16, 9), (14, 8), (6, 10), (16, 10), (15, 12), (12, 14), (17, 18), (17, 12), (10, 9), (4, 15)]
```

Note that I changed the string formatting to the `format()`-syntax, which in my opinion vastly increases readability. Please let me know if this is even close to what you are after.

Comment: No, this is good thanks. I'm really close. It's no prob but my actual dataset contain different names for the xy coordinates. So instead of A1_, it's John_. I can change them to A1-A2 etc but I thought I'd ask if there was an easy way to iterate through the columns. E.g GrA_X columns. Does that make sense.

Comment: @JPeter I guess you could iterate through the keys of the `DataFrame` an check if they contain certain substrings. Depends a bit on what the actual keys are.

Answer (score 1):

This could be an alternative solution, given I am understanding your problem correctly.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
X = [df[c].tolist() for c in df.columns if c.find("_X") >= 0]
Y = [df[c].tolist() for c in df.columns if c.find("_Y") >= 0]

allX = [x for sublist in X for x in sublist]
allY = [y for sublist in Y for y in sublist]

dfXY = pd.DataFrame({"X": allX, "Y":allY})
```

Now you have all x's and y's in a simple dataframe.
Cheers